# ASP VB .Net Convert string to Command

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, web, command

I am making a website (noob at this) and am trying to add search results to three divs. But problem arises when adding text to divs from database. It fetches correctly. but I want to convert a string (total three divs, id's respectively being div1, div2, div3. string being "div" + DivCount.ToString, DivCount being 0 (which loops and +1 is added every loop) into command. Here's the code, any other method would be appreciated too. Thanks. Code's below, btw.

Default.aspx.vb

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe

Partial Class Pages_Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    'Project Variables
    Dim ProjectDirectory As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString

    'ConnectAndAddItemsToDropdownList Dim
    Dim SQLCommandString As String
    Dim SQLConnectionString As String = "Data Source=" + ProjectDirectory + "App_Data\MainDatabase.sdf; Persist Security Info=False;"

    Dim SQLConnection As New SqlCeConnection(SQLConnectionString)
    Dim SQLAdapter As SqlCeDataAdapter
    Dim SQLReader As SqlCeDataReader
    Dim Executor As New MSScriptControl.ScriptControl

    Dim DivCount As Integer = 0
    Dim DivCurrent As String

    Public Sub ConnectAndAddItemsToDropdownList()
        DropDownList1.Items.Clear()
        SQLConnection.Open()
        SQLCommandString = "SELECT BookName FROM [Anthony Horowitz] WHERE (BookName LIKE '" + SearchTextBox.Text + "%')"
        Dim SQLCommand As New SqlCeCommand(SQLCommandString, SQLConnection)
        SQLReader = SQLCommand.ExecuteReader()
        While SQLReader.Read()
            DivCount = +1
            DivCurrent = "div" + DivCount.ToString
            Executor.Language = "VBScript"
            Executor.Eval(DivCurrent.ToString + ".InnerText = SQLReader(""Bookname"")")
        End While
        SQLConnection.Close()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub SearchTextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchTextBox.TextChanged
        ConnectAndAddItemsToDropdownList()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="Pages_Default" AutoEventWireUp="False"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body id="MainPage" runat="server">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="SearchTextBox" Text="Search for a book here..." runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="SearchTextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="17px" Width="105px"></asp:DropDownList>
            <div id="div1" runat="server">Nothing Interesting</div>
            <div id="div2" runat="server">Nothing Interesting</div>
            <div id="div3" runat="server">Nothing Interesting</div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result above is "object required: 'div1'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get data like that and put it in elements, for three reasons:

- The script doesn't have access to your SQL Reader.
- The elements doesn't exist yet, all the server code has already ended before they do.
- When the elements come to exist, they exist on a different computer.

Put server controls in the markup where you want the text:

```
<div id="div1" runat="server"><asp:Label runat="server" id="label1" Text="Nothing Interesting" /></div>
```

Get references to the controls and put in an array so that you can easily access them:

```
Dim labels(2) as Label
labels(0) = label1
labels(1) = label2
labels(2) = label3
```

Now you can put the data in the controls:

```
While SQLReader.Read()
  labels(DivCount).Text = SQLReader("Bookname")
  DivCount = +1
End While
```

Comment: Agree with your second thingy regarding labels(and thats all i needed) but I still cant get the point of the first point(cool, eh?). Would you please explain me that? And thanks, by the way, for your quick reply. And while you are at it, please elaborate the array bit also.Thanks

Comment: @RaithathaDhruvit: You are creating a new script that runs in its own context, it doesn't have access to any variables in your VB code.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance and as I said, I didn't exactly understamd the labels dimpart

Comment: @RaithathaDhruvit: The array is just so that you can access the labels by using a number, otherwise you would need to put together a name using `"label" & DivCount` and use `FindControl` to look through the controls in the page to find the labels.

Comment: That's cool, but I have never used an array, so can I make a request and ask you to write the small piece of code in the next post. Thank You again for your assistance.

Comment: @RaithathaDhruvit: This is not a chat. I'm not at the computer 24/7, so it may be a while before I answer. What small piece of code are you talking about?

Comment: Yeah, sorry but I was kind of getting sleepy yesterday, my bad. But I was talking about this : Dim labels(2) as Label
labels(0) = label1
labels(1) = label2
labels(2) = label3
How am I supposed to type that in the code page exactly. And today was a festival in India and so I was out the whole day, so sorry for the late response.

Comment: @RaithathaDhruvit: You can put in the code behind file where you declare the other variables.

Comment: I know how to do that, I just you know, Is this format right              Dim SQLConnection As New SqlCeConnection(SQLConnectionString)
    Dim SQLAdapter As SqlCeDataAdapter
    Dim SQLReader As SqlCeDataReader
    Dim labels(2) As Label
    labels(0) = label1
    labels(1) = label2
    labels(2) = label3 (please take at look at the code in question) and so it shows an error

Comment: @RaithathaDhruvit: Ah, right. You need to put the assignments inside the method, and then you can put the declaration there also.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance so far. I put the rest together and got what I wanted, so thanks.